# Error while working with OpenMP: Parallel reduction calculation is invalid

Tags: c, openmp

While working with C and OpenMP to use parallel processing on a set of data I keep getting the following errors with my for loops.

```
Parallel reduction calculation is invalid!
Parallel atomic calculation is invalid!
```

The code is:

```
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(numberOfThreads \
       reduction(+:number_in_circle) shared(count)
for(count = 0; count < iterations; count++)
    //calculate number in circle

# pragma omp parallel for num_threads(numberOfThreads) private(x, y,\
      dist_sqrd) shared(count, number_in_circle, iterations)
for(count = 0; count < iterations; count++)
    //calculate number_in_circle using atomic instruction to add to it.
```

Is there something wrong with my syntax or is it something wrong with the loop itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure your copy of the OpenMP directives is 100% correct but there are definitely issues on the ones here:

```
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(numberOfThreads \
       reduction(+:number_in_circle) shared(count)
for(count = 0; count < iterations; count++)
```

- `num_threads(numberOfThreads` misses the closing parenthesis
- `shared(count)` is invalid since `count` is the index of the `for` loop you want to parallelise. Trying to define such index private is both stupid and [explicitly forbidden by the OpenMP standard](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/OpenMP4.0.0.pdf#G4.996952)
  This same remark goes for the second directive you cited.

Regarding the `atomic` and `reduction` clause errors, there isn't enough in your code snippet to give any advice.